# Switch to fluid layout on small screens in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a container class around my bootstrap 3 layout so that it has proper width for medium and large screens. However, it also affects small screens. I'd like to have a width of 100% for small screens (sm) and not only for extra small screens (xs). In other words I'd like to suppress the effect of the container for small screens. Is there a simple way to achieve this without defining my own container classes and media queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think only way to get exactly what you want is to define your own `container`.

Another option is to use `col-sm-12` as a full width wrapper instead. However, this will also be wide on `md` and `lg`

Or, you could use `col-md-10` for a narrower wrap on `md` and `lg`, then switch to `col-sm-12` for full width `sm` and `xs`

See demo: http://bootply.com/111713

Comment: I think you are right, I have to define my own container. However, I figured out it's not so difficult so I will just do that.